# Distributing points on the n-sphere: Special cases

Tags: geometry

My understanding is that there is no general closed-form solution to the task of maximally separating $k$ points on an $n$-sphere ($S^n$).

But I wonder if this problem has known solutions when $k$ and $n$ satisfy some conditions.

I am wondering specifically whether we can evenly distribute $k\in\{2^{i},2^{i+1},2^{i+2},\ldots \}$ on $S^{2^i-1}\subset \mathbb{R}^{2^i}$.

In other words, consider the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n$ a power of $2$. Do we have closed form solutions to evenly distribute $2n$ points on the sphere of that space ($S^{n-1}$)? what about $4n$ points? $8n$? $2^jn$?

Apart from the trivial solutions for $n=2$, my intuition tells me we can always maximally separate $k = 2n$ points in $S^{n-1}$ (e.g. choose $e_i$ and $-e_i$ for all coordinates)

Edit:

By "maximally separating $k$ points on an $n$-sphere" I would try to formalise like this:

$$\arg max_{S\subset S^n, |S|=k}\min\{\|s_i-s_j\|:\forall s_i, s_j \in S\} $$

where as usual

$$S^n=\{p\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:\|p\|=1\}$$

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate what it means to have $k$ maximally separated points?

Comment: @flawr just did!

Comment: It is much clearer now. I first was not sure whether you maybe mean e.g. the angle (defined via scalar product) as a distance between two points.